# Can't get WinAppDeployCmd for Appx deployment to work

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10

During the [App Packaging and Deployment for Universal Windows Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-695) presentation (fast forward to **00:36:00**) one specific command line utility - **WinAppDeployCmd** - was used for deployment Windows 10 Universal application to the phone running Windows 10 Mobile. This utility could be found here:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\WinAppDeployCmd.exe"
```

But every time I'm trying to deploy sample `.appx` package to the Lunia 635 phone with Windows Mobile v**10.0.12562.84** *or* Surface 3 device with Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (all devices on the same network as my dev machine) - I'm getting the same "connection failed" error:

> Windows App Deployment Tool Version
>
> 10.0.0.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft
>
> Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Opening connection to device at '192.168.1.139'.
>
> 0x80131500 - Connection Failed
>
> 0x800705B4 - Timed out waiting for
>   network events.

Just in case - I could ping both of the devices from my dev machine without problem and can also deploy to any of them from VS2015RC (also tried with renamed `WinAppDeployCmd.exe` - to make sure that VS2015RC doing deployment somehow differently without using this tool).

So, I'm wondering - are there anyone who succeeded with app deployment using `WinAppDeployCmd.exe`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in the current release. There is no workaround and it will light up in a future Windows 10 Insider Preview SDK and tools release.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c8d6f20-699c-4da2-9460-f73e89bf27c3/known-issue-cannot-sideload-applications-using-winappdeploycmd-windows-10-insider-preview-sdk-and?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues

Answer (score 2):

I have succeeded to deploy an .appx using the WinAppDeployCmd command line tool. Probably the issue have been correct at the latest versions.

For the ones that are not familiar with this tool, it allows you to deploy an Universal Windows app from a Windows 10 machine to any Windows 10 Mobile device via USB or WiFi (since they're on the same subnet). That's a perfect solution if you doesn't have Visual Studio, doesn't have the app source code or if you're under a Hyper-V Virtual Machine.

Basically you will need:

1. [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
2. Generate the .appx package (PC)
3. Enable the developer mode (Mobile)
4. Turn on the discovery mode (Mobile)
5. Get the code to pair devices (Mobile)
6. Get mobile IP address using WinAppDeployCmd tool (PC)
7. Run command (PC)

The command will look like this

```
WinAppDeployCmd install -file “<path>” -ip <ip> -pin <pin>
```

The tool can be found at C:\Arquivos de Programas (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\WinAppDeployCmd.exe

You can find a detailed step-by-step tutorial [here](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/06/deploy-remoto-de-universal-windows-apps/)

Comment: That worked for me with the appx rather than the appxbundle.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me once when the USB socket was faulty and Windows compained about the device not being recognized. I switched sockets and everything worked. So make sure you try other sockets (or even a different computer, to rule out the specific machine).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but in my case that was the same to all of my laptop's USB sockets.

Comment: Sure thing. Can't hurt to have this here though for anyone else who might run into it..

Answer (score 0):

This tool let's you install but does not run the app after install like it did the first version in windows 8.1

Comment: Isn't that a comment ?